# Uploading files to the s3 bucket

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload my files to the s3 bucket, but i don't want that file to be uploaded from my local machine instead when some one uses the application and uploads a file the same should be directly uploaded to my s3 bucket.!! Is there a way to do this?(code should be in .net)

```
            string filekey = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            using (MemoryStream filebuffer = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)))
            {
                PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = this.awsBucketName,
                    Key = "GUARD1" + "/" + filekey,
                    InputStream = filebuffer,
                    ContentType = "application/pkcs8",
                };
```

This is what i am doing..which in turn creates a folder in the bucket and takes the file path from the local machine and the same is uploaded to the bucket.

What i need is that the file shouldn't be saved in the local machine and instead be taken directly from the application to the s3 bucket.

This is WriteIntoS3 method:

```
string filekey = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                using (MemoryStream filebuffer = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)))
                {
                    PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = this.awsBucketName,
                        Key = "GUARD1" + "/" + filekey,
                        InputStream = filebuffer,
                        ContentType = "application/pkcs8",
                    };

                    client.PutObject(putRequest);

                    GetPreSignedUrlRequest expiryUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
                    expiryUrlRequest.BucketName = this.awsBucketName;
                    expiryUrlRequest.Key = filekey;
                    expiryUrlRequest.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(ExpiryDays);

                    string url = client.GetPreSignedURL(expiryUrlRequest);
                    return url;
                }
```

Comment: we are here to help you if you got error not here to make code for you

Comment: post your code first so we can see where were you may wrong

Comment: @PranavPatel sir i don't want someone to code for me! But is there a way that this can be done!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use local files then you can use **TransferUtility** class to upload a stream directly to S3.

For example:

```
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) // Load the data into memorystream from a data source other than a file
        {
            using (var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client))
            {
                transferUtility.Upload(ms, "bucket", "key");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Just had to add the region like so: var client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1)